# Can't access dynamically a dictionary with Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, dynamic, swift2

I'm using Swift 2 and XCode 7.2, and I'm trying to get Dictionary elements dynamically.

This is my dictionary located inside NSUserDefaults, that contains the user configuration:

```
let dicAlerts : [String : Int] = [
    "alertOne" : 1,
    "alertTwo" : 1,
    "alertThree" : 1,
    "alertFour" : 1,
    "alertFive" : 1,
    "alertSix" : 1,
    "alertSeven" : 1
]
```

If I do a print of this, everything looks fine:

**Code:**

```
        let alerts = userSettings.dictionaryForKey("alerts")!

    print(alerts)
```

**Output:**

> ["alertSix": 1, "alertSeven": 1, "alertThree": 1, "alertTwo": 1, "alertFive": 1, "alertOne":
>   1, "alertFour": 1]

The user can configure this from a settings panel, with the following code I have a list of all my static cells from a UITable, if I do a print of item.reuseIdentifier I can see the correct value (alertOne, alertTwo, alertThree, alertFour, alertFive, alertSix, alertSeven):

```
for (_, item) in alertRows.enumerate() {
    let key : String = item.reuseIdentifier!
    print(alerts[key]!)
}
```

There's a reason that I'm not being able to determine, but the code above doesn't works.

> fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
>   (lldb)

**The following does:**

```
print(alerts["alertSix"])
```

> 1

The question is Why dynamically it doesn't work, and when I hardcode the key it does?

How can I make it work?

And what is even weird for me is that if you print the key separately you get the key, but when you put it inside the dictionary is does not work.

This will be the complete example:

```
// Get the user settings
let userSettings = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

@IBOutlet weak var alertOne: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var alertTwo: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var alertThree: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var alertFour: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var alertFive: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var alertSix: UITableViewCell!
@IBOutlet weak var alertSeven: UITableViewCell!

// Array of alerts
var alertRows: [UITableViewCell] {
    return [alertOne, alertTwo, alertThree, alertFour, alertFive, alertSix, alertSeven]
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let alerts = userSettings.dictionaryForKey("alerts")!

    print(alerts) // OK

    for (_, item) in alertRows.enumerate() {

        let key : String = item.reuseIdentifier!

        print(key) // OK = return alertOne
        print(alerts["alertOne"]) // OK = return 1
        print(alerts[key]) // ERROR described above (unexpectedly found nil while [...])

        if alerts[key] == 1 {

            item.accessoryType = .Checkmark
        } else {

            item.accessoryType = .None
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: print `item.reuseIdentifier!` to see what they yield. At what line does it crash btw? Please combine all your code snippets into one complete example, *where* do you print *what*? Where does it crash?

Comment: Updated, I was just doing that

Comment: Most likely your crash occurs at line `print(alerts[key]!)`, as the `key` for some reason is not found in your existing dictionary `alerts`. You should avoid forced unwrapping like this, an instead use something along the lines `print(alerts[key] ?? "Could not find key '\(key)' in dictionary.")`

Comment: Are you 100% sure there is no typo or whitespace or anything? `print(key == "alertOne")`

Comment: @luk2302 thanks that was the issue. I was mixing the key names. What a stupid mistake :/ Thanks.